# Piping stdout in C

Tags: c, function, pipe

I would like to know how can I pipe stdout in c. Here is an example of piping the stdout of the command 'ls' from linux, storing it in a variable, and then printing the value of the variable:

```
import subprocess
#Piping stdout of the command 'ls' from linux
test = subprocess.Popen("ls", stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
stdoutpiped = test.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
print(stdoutpiped)
```

Results from the running code:

```
Destkop
Documents
Images
Videos
Downloads
MyCodes
passwords.txt
```

How would you do this in `c`?

Thank you!

Comment: You'll have to use OS specific functions for that (unless there is something for it in the new standards coming out. I don't see it in filesystem.) Should come up on a search if you know your OS.

Comment: POSIX defines `popen()`.  You should have that available on Mac and Linux.  Windows has `_popen()`, but with caveats.  Other alternatives exist, too, but none in the C standard library. Do take care to read the appropriate docs.

Comment: As an aside, the Python snippet is (nominally) buggy: you want `Popen(["ls"])` or `Popen("ls", shell=True)` but not any compromise where the shell receives a list of tokens, or you pass in a bare string without `shell=True`.  It currently happens to work, but this is an implementation detail which could - and even perhaps should - change.  Also, for this particular use case, you want `subprocess.check_output()` or the modern replacement `subprocess.run()` rather than bare `Popen()` with the associated plumbing you have to do to reimplement `check_output()` (incompletely).

Comment: Extra points for having a folder called `Destkop` to befuddle your enemies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this using popen as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PATH_MAX 1000

int main( ) {

    FILE *fp;
    int status;
    char path[PATH_MAX];


    fp = popen("ls *", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    /* Handle error */;


    while (fgets(path, PATH_MAX, fp) != NULL)
        printf("%s", path);


    status = pclose(fp);
    if (status == -1) {
        /* Error reported by pclose() */
        printf("Error, reported");
    } else {
        /* Use macros described under wait() to inspect `status' in order
         to determine success/failure of command executed by popen() */
        printf("Done running");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You'll find more information [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/popen.html).